# How to clean an url after search by using GET with laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the method GET to search some records in my database

```
<form id="cliente" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('resultados_clientes')}}" method="get">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label" for="cliente"></label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input form="cliente" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="cliente" type="text" name="cliente" placeholder="Introduzca el rif o nombre del cliente a buscar" required>
            <br>
            <div class="pull-right">
            <button form="cliente" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">
              Buscar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

The problem is that when I found something and I return to my page for search it returns with the parameters of the search in the url... I would like to clean that.. How could I do?

this is the function of my controller

```
public function resultados_clientes(Request $request){
  $busqueda = $request->cliente;
  $clientes = strtoupper($busqueda);
  $perimetro = DB::table('tbl_perimetros as a')
    ->select('a.id','a.rif','a.cod_cliente','a.razon_social','a.holdings_id')
    ->leftjoin('tbl_holdings as b','b.id','=','a.holdings_id')
    ->select(array('a.id','b.hrif','b.hrazon_social','a.rif','a.razon_social','a.estatus'))
    ->where('a.rif','like', '%' . $clientes . '%')
    ->orWhere('a.razon_social', 'like', '%' . $clientes . '%')
    ->orWhere('b.hrif', 'like', '%' . $clientes . '%')
    ->orWhere('b.hrazon_social', 'like', '%' . $clientes . '%')  
    ->get();

  if($perimetro->count()) {
    return view('Busqueda_est.resultados_clientes',compact('perimetro','busqueda'));
  }

  $error_code = 1;
   return view('Busqueda_est.index', compact('error_code'));

}
```

I would like to do a kind of function or something like that in the .blade maybe with javascript or php

Here is my .web

```
/*BUSQUEDA ESTANDAR*/
Route::namespace('Busquedaest')->group(function () {
Route::get('busqueda_est', 'BusquedaestController@index')->name('busqueda_est');
Route::get('busqueda_est-resultados-clientes', 'BusquedaestController@resultados_clientes')->name('resultados_clientes');
});
```

Comment: Hmm, why not use a POST instead of GET?

Comment: I don't know how to change my function to POST method

Comment: can I see your web.php file? I will let you know how to change it

Comment: Just an FYI, you seem to be missing a closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: I updated my question @EbrahimMohammed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use POST instead of GET. to do that , change your html form to:

```
<form id="cliente" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('resultados_clientes')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label" for="cliente"></label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input form="cliente" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="cliente" type="text" name="cliente" placeholder="Introduzca el rif o nombre del cliente a buscar" required>
        <br>
        <div class="pull-right">
        <button form="cliente" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">
          Buscar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

in your web.php replace:

```
Route::get('busqueda_est-resultados-clientes', 'BusquedaestController@resultados_clientes')->name('resultados_clientes');
```

With:

```
Route::post('busqueda_est-resultados-clientes', 'BusquedaestController@resultados_clientes')->name('resultados_clientes');
```

Comment: I obtained this 419
Page Expired

Comment: Have you added the @csrf to the <form> ?

Comment: my bad... I missed that... thanks a lot my friend.. you helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to make ajax call to the server to fetch all records.
Using `POST` method would work, but it would result in the dialog popping up each time you'd like to reload the page in some browsers.

Depending on whether you are using any JavaScript framework there are different ways to achieve this.

My preferred framework is VueJs and I'm actually going to be streaming a screencast this Friday on how to build search component - you're welcome to join: https://youtu.be/FJ1MaNtjPDs

With `VueJs` (or even straight JavaScript) you can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) call, which would look something like that:

```
axios.get('/your-end-point-here')
  .then(function (response) {
      // use response.data with the returned data for the list
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: VueJs all the way! But sometimes people want to keep it simple, specially when dealing with simple customers! upvoted.

Comment: Thanks - absolutely, hence I'm trying to find out whether he's using any framework or not as it can also be achieved with just vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a method GET you will have the parameters on the url.
In order to not have them visible, you should be using the POST method instead.